# Oracle: How to find overlaps in rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following table:

```
User_ID Activity_ID
123     222
123     333
124     222
124     224
124     333
125     224
125     333
```

I want to return a count users by the different combinations of overlaps such as the following:

```
Activity_ID_1 Activity_ID_2 Count_of_Users
222           333           2 
222           224           2
```

In the above example, there are 2 users who completed both 223 AND 333.

I do not want to define each combination manually since there are 93 different activity_ids I am working with. Is there a way to do this purely in Oracle SQL?

Comment: I only see user `124` as having covered the range `222` to `224`.

Comment: what if some users completed 3 activities (the same 3 activities), how you would like to see output?

Comment: I am not interested in the range as much as the activity ids themselves. For example, both user 123 and 124 completed activities 222 and 333, do the count of users for that combination should be 2.

Comment: @Lashane I think we are only interested in overlaps of 2 activities versus 3. I was thinking of using some type of outer join on activity id.

Comment: Why "outer" join if you are interested in activities that were actually completed? Then: Do you have a separate "activity" table? (Assuming you do, with activity_id PK in that table and FK in this "facts" table - right?)

Comment: What happens if the same user had activities 222 and 333, both of them at least twice, but no other users had these activities? Does that still count as "at least 2" or not?

Comment: @mathguy Correct, there is a separate activity table. The activity_id represented in the sample "user_activity" table is a FK. I think if I join the user_activity table with itself on activity_id <> activity_id, it would let me get every possible combination, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but you should join on activity_id (from first copy of the table) < activity_id (from second copy); otherwise you will get the same information, once shown for activities 222, 333 and then again for 333, 222.

Comment: @mathguy I had used a distinct statement to filter the data table so each activity id and user_id combination occurs once, even if a user completed the same activity id multiple times.

Comment: @mathguy Ah yes, my next question was going to be how to solve the 222, 333 vs 333, 222 situation, but your solution of table1.activity_id < table1copy.activity_id works fine. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `activity` table with activity id's, and you want to count only DISTINCT users who had the same two activities (the same user having both activities twice wouldn't count):

```
select a1.activity_id, a2.activity_id, count(distinct f.user_id)
from   activity a1 inner join facts    f  on a1.activity_id = f.activity_id
                   inner join activity a2 on a2.activity_id = f.activity_id
where  a1.activity_id < a2.activity_id
group by a1.activity_id, a2.activity_id
having count(distinct f.user_id) >= 2
;
```

`facts` is the name of your facts table (the one you show in your question).

EDIT:  If the `facts` table (or view or subquery or whatever) is already "distinct"-ed by user_id, then delete "distinct" from my solution; this will make it more efficient. NOTE: "distinct" appears twice, once in SELECT and again in HAVING.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. The only thing I have to add is, sometimes I get a row of activity_id1 filled, but activity_id2 null, which I solved by setting `where activity_id2 is not null`

Comment: @datatista - Oh... you are right, in general NULL is not equal to anything else, but in GROUP BY nulls are grouped together. Good catch and solution!  However... on second thought... from the inner joins, and activity_id being PK in table activity, how do you get NULL in the result of my query in the first place? I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( User_ID, Activity_ID ) AS
SELECT 123, 222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 224 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 125, 224 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 125, 333 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE INTLIST AS TABLE OF INT;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH Activities ( User_IDs, Activity_ID ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( COLLECT( User_ID ) AS INTLIST ),
         Activity_ID
  FROM   data
  GROUP BY Activity_ID
)
SELECT a.Activity_ID,
       b.Activity_ID,
       CARDINALITY( a.User_IDs MULTISET INTERSECT b.User_IDs ) AS "Count"
FROM   Activities a
       INNER JOIN
       Activities b
       ON ( CARDINALITY( a.User_IDs MULTISET INTERSECT b.User_IDs ) > 1
           AND a.Activity_ID < b.Activity_ID );
```

**Output**:

```
ACTIVITY_ID ACTIVITY_ID      Count
----------- ----------- ----------
        222         333          2 
        224         333          2
```